# Going to a link with right click

Tags: javascript, html

I have several table cells of the type:

```
<td oncontextmenu=";return false;">
   <a href="..."title="Hydrogen">H</a><br>
    2.20
</td>
```

My question is: How to make a javascript that captures the title of the link, and goes to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TITLE_OF_THE_LINK when I right-click in the coresponding cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is basically this:

HTML:

```
<td oncontextmenu="goTitle(this); return false">
    <a href="#" title="hydrogen">h</a>
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
function goTitle(el) {
    var link = el.firstChild;
    var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + link.title;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

For simplicity, it's assumed your link is always the first element in your `td`

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location` to redirect the user.

**HTML**

```
<td oncontextmenu="gotoWiki(event);return false;">
   <a href="..."title="Hydrogen">H</a><br>
    2.20
</td>
```

**JS**

```
function gotoWiki(event) {
    // Extract the target from the event
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    // Get the link
    var link;
    if (target.tagName == "A") {
        // If the target is an <a>-Tag, it's the link
        link = target;
    } else {
        // Otherwise, get the first <a>-Tag
        link = target.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    }
    // If getElementsByTagName() returned an element and it has the title attribute
    if (link && title = link.getAttribute("title")) {
        // Redirect
        window.location.href = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `(event.target || event.srcElement)` will give you the link when the context menu handler is bound to `td`? Shouldn't you search for the `a` first to get the right element?

Comment: @Luaan I would bind the event to the entire table that contains these links, but you can choose whatever element that is a direct or indirect parent of the link. Besides that, `event.target` and `event.srcElement` return the actual clicked element, whether it has the event bound on itself or one of its parents.

Comment: Yes, but I expect that the link doesn't actually fill the whole td (otherwise why not have oncontextmenu or whatever on the link instead?). So you'd get the td, rather than the link.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you bind the event with `onContextmenu=""` in the HTML. Let me correct my answer real quick...

Comment: Now this should work. Thanks to @Luaan for pointing some things out.